# Serving static files directly via a containerized front-end web server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker Compose file with a couple of PHP/FastCGI-based web applications that I want to expose via Nginx (3 containers in total). If the two web app containers store their static files on "/var/www/html", how can I get the Nginx container to serve the static files **directly**?

I cannot find a way to do this at all, meaning that I have to get the two web apps to serve their own static files. And this would require moving from FastCGI to HTTP if I cannot change the application code (as is the case here).

This could be doable if there were a way to mount container volumes on different paths, just like you can do it with the host system. Is there any way to accomplish something like this, other than doing it via the host system?

Comment: I'm a bit new to docker myself, but maybe you could get the Nginx container to mount the appropriate portion of the filesystems of the other two containers? Something like this perhaps: http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html

Comment: Thanks @neuronaut! I believe you're referring to the "volumes-from" option, and I think it wouldn't work because the two web app containers have "/var/www/html" as the volume.

Answer (score 3):

A solution would be to mount `/var/www/html` folder directly to nginx to use the nginx feature of [serving static files](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/). I also suggest for simplicity to use a [data-container](https://medium.com/@ramangupta/why-docker-data-containers-are-good-589b3c6c749e) to mount the html folder to all 3 containers. The final docker-compose.yml would looks like this:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
   - 80:80
  links:
   - app1
   - app2
  volumes_from:
   - html
 app1:
   image: [app1]
   volumes_from:
    - html
 app2:
   image: [app2]
   volumes_from:
    - html
html:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
   - html:/var/www/html
```

and the nginx configuration would be like this:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
        ...
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /var/www/html/images;
    }

    location ~ \.(mp3|mp4) {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

The above configuration will server `/images` folder and any `mp3/mp4` files throught the static resources.

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't this require the static files in app1 and app2 to be identical? It also seems to restrict the static files that can be served to those of app1/app2

Comment: Yes the static files are identical in this case. If you need different files for different apps, the `html` data-container is not needed and you can get the volumes from apps using `volumes_from` app1/app2 or even server other static files using `volumes` directive. Ofcourse you need to change nginx configuration accordingly.